# (android) How to place a view below other views in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

[image]

This picture is state of `layout`

I want to place the `RecyclerView` below the `Button`

However, as you can see, even with `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`, the `RecyclerView` is not placed

under the `Button`

There is a condition, the size of the `RecyclerView` must be `math_parent`.

This is because you are using a nested `recycler view` and you are dynamically adding items, otherwise

the last nested `recycler view's item` will be cut off and not visible when adding dynamically..

If I set the height of a view to match_parent in the constraint layout, is there any way to place it

below other views?

This is XML file.

activity_write_routine.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".data.DailyRecordDetailActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body_part_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="P A R T"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_routine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A D D"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_green"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/routine_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_routine"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the height to 0dp, and constraint the bottom of recyclerview to parent

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/routine_recyclerview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_routine"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, isn't this something like `wrap_contetnt`?
The height of the `RecyclerView` is `match_parent` and I want to place it under the button.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally forgot a code. Your code was the right answer. Thank you